# Show $f(x) = (x,y_0)$ is an embedding where $x \in X, y_0 \in Y$ (fixed) for $X,Y$ topological spaces.

Tags: general-topology

I know definition of embedding.

$f: X \to X \times Y$

$f(x) = (x,y_0)$ is a horizontal strip in $X \times Y$

I need to show $f,\pi_1$ where $\pi_1: X \times Y \to X$ by $\pi_1(x,y) = x$ are both continuous.

I start with $B$ open in $X \times Y$ and with product topology $B = U \times V$ where $U,V$ are open in $X,Y$ receptively.

Here $\pi_1(B) = \pi_1(U \times V)= U$ which is open in $X$

Now take $M$ open in $X$ then, $(\pi_1)^{-1}(M) = M \times Y$.

Comment: @abspht "Imbedding" is an acceptable spelling variant of "embedding".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $B$ is an arbitrary open subset of $X\times Y$, it’s not necessarily true that $B=U\times V$ for open sets $U\subseteq X$ and $V\subseteq Y$: all you know is that it’s a *union* of sets of that form. Moreover, the range of $f$ is $X\times\{y_0\}$, so

$$f^{-1}[B]=f^{-1}[B\cap(X\times\{y_0\})]=\pi_1[B\cap(X\times\{y_0\})]\;,$$

not $\pi_1[B]$.

HINT: Use the facts that

- you need only show that inverse images of *basic* open sets are open in order to conclude that $f$ is continuous,
- that sets of the form $U\times V$ for open sets $U\subseteq X$ and $V\subseteq Y$ are a base for the product topology, and hence that
- sets of the form $(U\times V)\cap(X\times\{y_0\})$ for open sets $U\subseteq X$ and $V\subseteq Y$ are a base for the topology of $X\times\{y_0\}$.

For the other direction, observe that if $M$ is open in $X$, then $M\times\{y_0\}=(M\times Y)\cap(X\times\{y_0\})$, and this is open in $X\times\{y_0\}$; why?

Comment: The last comment I know you want me to say that it is open by subspace topology property buy why is $M \times Y$ open in $X \times Y$?

Comment: @Mr.Fry: Because $M$ is open in $X$, and $Y$ is open in $Y$: $M\times Y$ is a basic open set in the product $X\times Y$.

Comment: Yeah that was a lapse by me.

Comment: $B \cap (X \times \{y_0\}) = \emptyset$ just some open interval on the space $X \times \{y_0\}$m but how do I interpret $\pi_1$ of this?

Comment: @Mr.Fry: I wouldn’t use the term *interval*, since the space need not have any kind of order; however, $B\cap(X\times\{y_0\})$ is an open *set* in $X\times\{y_0\}$, by definition of the subspace topology. Don’t try to compute $\pi_1$ of it directly, unless you’ve already assumed that $B$ is a basic open set in the product, i.e., that $B=U\times V$ for open $U\subseteq X$ and $V\subseteq Y$. Then you can conclude that either $y_0\notin V$, in which case the projection of $B\cap(X\times\{y_0\})$ is empty, or $y_0\in V$, in which case it’s $U$.

Comment: Ah ok. Well thank you.

Comment: @Mr.Fry: You’re welcome.

Comment: Here $\pi_1: X \times Y \to X$ so when we take an open $M$ in $X$ then $\pi_1^{-1}(M) = M \times Y$ which is open. So why are we looking at $M \times \{y_0\}$? Why are you showing inverse image open relative to $X \times \{y_0\}$?

Comment: @Mr.Fry: Because that's the range of $f$, the space that you want to show is homeomorphic to $X$.

Comment: I should of been corrected and had $\pi_1: X \times \{y_0\} \to X$ right?

Comment: @Mr.Fry: Either that, or taken $\pi_1:X\times Y\to X$ to be the usual projection map and used $\pi_1\upharpoonright(X\times\{y_0\})$, its restriction to $X\times\{y_0\}$.